# How to run an Android emulator on an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been looking to run an Android emulator on a cloud provider. I've tried using Genymotion and the built-in Android SDK emulator but both refuse to run in a virtual environment. I would rather not use Ravello as it is a separate paid service and it didn't work properly during the free trial (kept getting a black screen in the emulator).

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm part of Genymotion team.*

Genymotion Software cannot run as is on EC2 instances. There are many limitations on the nested virtualisation (Amazon instance -> VirtualBox -> Genymotion instance) that makes it impossible.

But we recently added a Genymotion device directly to the [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MREUQPU) so you can just manage Genymotion devices as AWS instances.

The onboarding is explained [here](https://www.genymotion.com/help/aws/product-access/) and a lot of videos are available on [our Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR3HcX37wekXBGvV_xTzEkQ) to explain some use cases.

For now only 6.0 is available but other versions are planned to be added.